# Java - Gherkin & Cucumber: Pass an object or list of objects on a vertical table instead of horizontal

Tags: java, java-8, cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

I have the following sample gherkin scenario on my feature file:

```
Scenario: Book an FX Trade
 Given trades with the following details are created:
   |buyCcy |sellCcy |amount   |date       |
   |EUR    |USD     |12345.67 |23-11-2017 |
   |GBP    |EUR     |67890.12 |24-11-2017 |
 When the trades are executed
 Then the trades are confirmed
```

In my glue file, I can map the data table to an object `Trade` as an out of the box cucumber solution:

```
@When("^trades with the following details are created:$")
public void trades_with_the_following_details_are_created(List<Trade> arg1) throws Throwable {
        //do something with arg1
}
```

**What I want to achieve:**
Improve the readability of my gherkin scenario by doing the following:

Transpose the data table vertically, This will improve readability if my object has around 10 fields

Replace fields / column names with aliases

**Sample:**

```
Scenario: Book an FX Trade
 Given trades with the following details are created:
   |Buy Currency  | EUR        | GBP        |
   |Sell Currency | USD        | EUR        |
   |Amount        | 12345.67   | 67890.12   |
   |Date          | 23-11-2017 | 24-11-2017 |
 When the trades are executed
 Then the trades are confirmed
```

I want the table to be dynamic in a way that it can have more or less than 2 data sets / columns. What would be the best way to achieve this?

**Additional info:**
Language: Java 8
Cucumber version: 1.2.5

`Trade` POJO being something like:

```
public class Trade {
    private String buyCcy;
    private String sellCcy;
    private String amount;
    private String date;

    /**
     * These fields are growing and may have around 10 or more....
     * private String tradeType;
     * private String company;
     */

    public Trade() {
    }

    /**
     * accessors here....
     */
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the table is specified in your feature file as

```
|buyCcy  | EUR        | GBP        |
|sellCcy | USD        | EUR        |
|amount  | 12345.67   | 67890.12   |
|date    | 23-11-2017 | 24-11-2017 |
```

you can use the following glue code (with your posted `Trade` class, assuming that there is a proper `toString()` method implemented)

```
@Given("^trades with the following details are created:$")
public void tradeWithTheFollowingDetailsAreCreated(DataTable dataTable) throws Exception {
    // transpose - transposes the table from the feature file
    // asList - creates a `List<Trade>`
    List<Trade> list = dataTable.transpose().asList(Trade.class);
    list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

output

```
Trade{buyCcy=EUR, sellCcy=USD, amount=12345.67, date=23-11-2017}
Trade{buyCcy=GBP, sellCcy=EUR, amount=67890.12, date=24-11-2017}
```

Comment: plus 1 for the effort, but I simply *hate* cucumber tests and their way to set them up...

Comment: @Eugene Out of curiosity. What do you propose instead of [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#java) for [BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development)?

Comment: that's a very good question... next question? seriously I don't know; all I can tell that there is zero pleasure involved when I have to do these tests (hey I even re-fused workplaces where I *knew* I had to do this)... especially when these tests get *big* - you probably understand what I mean

Comment: Never knew it was this simple. I feel a bit ashamed I didn't check DataTable methods first XD. Thanks!!